# Problem in a customized permission in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions, user-permissions

I tried to make a customized permission class which ensures that the user is authenticated and the authenticated user trying to access the endpoint is accessing information related to him not another user.
This is the customized class:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class IsAuthenticatedAndSameUser(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method == "GET" or request.method == 'DELETE':
            print(request.user)
            if request.user.is_authenticated and (request.user == obj.user):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

I gave the Viewset the new customized class in permission classes.

```
class AccountViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedAndSameUser,)
    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'], permission_classes=(IsAuthenticatedAndSameUser, ))
    def orders(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
```

The permission class works fine when I try to access endpoints related to the Account model directly like: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/accounts/2/
But it doesn't work as expected on the action decorator. When I use the endpoint related to the action decorator: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/accounts/2/orders/. The class uses the `has_permission` function instead of `has_object_permission` function in `IsAuthenticatedAndSameUser` class.
I want it to use the `has_object_permission` function.

Models used:
Account model

```
class Account(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=9)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Name: {self.user.username} / Balance: {self.balance}'
```

Order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'AccountOf: {self.account.user.username} / ProductName: {self.product.name}'
```

I tried to customise the `get_permissions` function inside viewset but it didn't work either.